# Ordering on two criteria, SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

[image]

Above is my output from my query.  I would like to alphabetize the dischargetype while also grouping metro, appalachia and rural `TRUES` together i.e. all the 1s for metro, rural and appalachia are in the right order, but how do i alphabetize the first column.  Below is my query

```
SELECT     tblDischarge.dischargeType, COUNT(tblDischarge.dischargeType) AS counts, tblVisits.diabetes, tblVisits.hemiplegia, tblKentuckyCounties.Metro, 
                      tblKentuckyCounties.Appalachia, tblKentuckyCounties.Rural
FROM         tblKentuckyCounties INNER JOIN
                      tblVisits ON tblKentuckyCounties.countyID = tblVisits.countyID INNER JOIN
                      tblDischarge ON tblVisits.DischargeStatus = tblDischarge.dis_statID
WHERE     (tblVisits.diabetes = 1) AND (tblVisits.hemiplegia = 1)
GROUP BY tblDischarge.dischargeType, tblVisits.diabetes, tblVisits.hemiplegia, tblKentuckyCounties.Metro, tblKentuckyCounties.Appalachia, tblKentuckyCounties.Rural
HAVING      (tblDischarge.dischargeType LIKE '%routine%') OR
                      (tblDischarge.dischargeType LIKE '%short-term%') OR
                      (tblDischarge.dischargeType LIKE '%icf%') OR
                      (tblDischarge.dischargeType = 'home health') OR
                      (tblDischarge.dischargeType LIKE '%swing%') OR
                      (tblDischarge.dischargeType LIKE 'rehab%') OR
                      (tblDischarge.dischargeType LIKE '%long-term%')
ORDER BY tblKentuckyCounties.Appalachia, tblKentuckyCounties.Rural, tblKentuckyCounties.Metro
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change last line to:

```
ORDER BY tblKentuckyCounties.Appalachia, tblKentuckyCounties.Rural, tblKentuckyCounties.Metro, tblDischarge.dischargeType
```

Comment: Thanks, you were the first to answer correctly, you get the prize :)

Answer (score 1):

```
ORDER BY tblKentuckyCounties.Appalachia, tblKentuckyCounties.Rural, tblKentuckyCounties.Metro, tblDischarge.dischargeType
```

should do it.

Comment: This will do it.  My problem in recognizing this initially was that there are some cases in which all of the criteria aren't met so the full result set I expected wasn't returned (not every region had TRUE for all the criteria).

Answer (score 0):

Just add tblDischarge.dischargeType to the ORDER BY as the first value.

```
ORDER BY tblDischarge.dischargeType, tblKentuckyCounties.Appalachia, tblKentuckyCounties.Rural, tblKentuckyCounties.Metro
```

**EDIT**

This can't be done, since you are trying to order by two completely different criteria.  You can only sub-order - each steps orders the results **within the previous step**, but you can only have one order.

Comment: doing this breaks the continuity between successive TRUES for the last three columns.

Comment: You want the TRUEs to be grouped but you ALSO want the first column to be alphabetized?   Can you provide an example, because I don't think that's possible.

Comment: Or do you want them alphabetized only within the sets of TRUEs?

Comment: It might not be, and it's looking like that's the case.  Everything I've tried hasn't worked so far, I don't think it can be done

Comment: Edited my answer to reflect that.